# Magento 2 in production mode use Dynamic/Developer factory?

Tags: magento2, code-generation, compilation, object-manager

I tried to search deeper in Magento 2 code generation process and found some points, which confused me.
I use Magento v2.0.1-ce in production mode.
**Firstly,** I found strange dependency in Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php:120

```
$definitions = $definitionFactory->createClassDefinition($deploymentConfig->get('definitions'));
```

I looked in console command **setup:config:set** help list and found only *'--definition-format'* parameter. I set it and got

```
'definition' => array ('format' => 'serialized',),
```

node in env.php. But it isn't requested param, so $deploymentConfig still return null.
The case in, that without this param, Magento 2 add Code Generation Autoload in autoload's chain.

```
public function createClassDefinition($definitions = false)
{
    if ($definitions) {
        if (is_string($definitions)) {
            $definitions = $this->_unpack($definitions);
        }
        $definitionModel = self::$definitionClasses[$this->_definitionFormat];
        $result = new $definitionModel($definitions);
    } else {
        $autoloader = new \Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader($this->getCodeGenerator());
        spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);

        $result = new Runtime();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So, question is: **what is *'definitions'* param in configs and in what way I should set it?** Or it is OK, that Magento 2 still use Code Generator Autoload in production mode? Finally, on what depend this param?
**Secondly,** after switch on production mode, Magento 2 called *'setup:di:compile-multi-tenant'* and I found, that file 'global.ser' doesn't generate with this command. As I understand, Magento 2 use this file for determination actual environment mode:
Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php:126

```
$env =  $enFactory->createEnvironment();
```

\Magento\Framework\App\EnvironmentFactory::createEnvironment

```
public function createEnvironment()
{
    switch ($this->getMode()) {
        case Compiled::MODE:
            return new Compiled($this);
            break;
        default:
            return new Developer($this);
    }
}
```

\Magento\Framework\App\EnvironmentFactory::getMode

```
const AREA_GLOBAL = 'global';

private function getMode()
{
    if (file_exists(ConfigLoader\Compiled::getFilePath(Area::AREA_GLOBAL))) {
        return Compiled::MODE;
    }

    return Developer::MODE;
}
```

\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader\Compiled::getFilePath

```
public static function getFilePath($area)
{
    return BP . '/var/di/' . $area . '.ser';
}
```

On environment depend ObjectManager factory and configs. So, after code generation via 'setup:di:compile-multi-tenant' Magento Object Manager will still work in developer mode?

Answer (score 1):

Code generator should not be added to autoload in production mode because all auto-generated entities are expected to be available in definition files (those with `.ser` extension). There is no need to modify `definitions` in config, just run `magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant`. In your case the problem is that definitions are not generated, try to investigate why.